# Change the color in django using css and python

Tags: python, css, django

I'm using Django framework to make an application of backup of the servers, before anything I need to check if my machines are online or not that's why I made this python script to check them:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#import the libs
import os
import sys
import time
#define My function
def GetStatus(SrvIP):
    rsl_ping = 0
    #execute the ping
    result = os.system("ping -c 1 "+ SrvIP +" >/dev/null ")
    os.system("clear")
    #check ping result
    if result == 0:
        rsl_ping = 1
    #if i got 0 that's mean the machine is shutdonw and 1 is running
    if rsl_ping == 0:
        print "Red;"
    else:
        print "Green;"
#the end my function should return 'Red' or 'Green' then put the resul inside the next line :
#

GetStatus("192.168.1.124")
```

After using that function it should tell me if  my machine is on or off and change the color in css style on the menu

```
  <ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav fixed collection white">
    <li class="collection-header"><img src="{% static 'images/logo1.png' %}" width="214"></li>
    {% for srv in Srvs %}
          {% csrf_token %}
            <li class="collection-item waves-effect waves-teal" onclick="serverId({{srv.id}})"  id="serverId"><a><i class="mdi-social-public" style="color: {{GetStatus:127.0.0.1}}"></i> {{ srv.name }} </a></li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
```

*file : /backup/home/template/base.html*

the issue is where should I put the script and how can I call it in my template to show it to users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you storing this ip ? in SRV instance ? if so !

you can do this way

```
class Server(model.Model):
    ip_adress - ....

    def check_status(self):
        rsl_ping = 0
        #execute the ping
        result = os.system("ping -c 1 "+ self.ip_adress +" >/dev/null ")
        os.system("clear")
        #check ping result
        if result == 0:
            rsl_ping = 1
        #if i got 0 that's mean the machine is shutdonw and 1 is running
        if rsl_ping == 0:
            return "Red;"
        else:
            return "Green;"
```

in your template you can

```
<li class="collection-item waves-effect waves-teal" onclick="serverId({{srv.id}})"  id="serverId"><a><i class="mdi-social-public" style="color: {{ srv.check_status }}"></i> {{ srv.name }} </a></li>
```

Comment: Where are you storing this ip ? : i store it in a table using Mysql server managed by PhpMyAdmin

Comment: sorry i meant your db model in models.py

Comment: sorry i didn't understand you well :(

Answer (score 0):

well you should spend some time on the nice Django tutorial to understand the architecture of a django project.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/overview/

Basically, you have models (for the objects to be stored in a database), views (to put your logic), and templates (to generate html pages for the website visitors). So your python code should be placed in the views.py, and the template code in the template/ dir. You should also manage the URLs so that user have access to the templates. But again, this would be much easier for you to follow the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

you don't call it in your template, you populate the data dictionary passed to your template rendering before calling the template's render.

```
def server_backup(request....):

    #some function you have to get the servers
    Srvs = get_server_list()

    #stick the color onto your srv instances - 
    #your function has to return red/green. not print it
    for srv in Srvs:
        srv.color = GetStatus(srv.SrvIP)


    di_context = dict(Srvs=Srvs)

    c = RequestContext(
    request,
    di_context,
    )

    t = get_template('<yourapp>/<yourtemplate>.html')
    html = t.render(c)
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

template - note the color variable in for the css class on your  tag.
note also the removal of your function call from the template and the use of **{{srv.color}}** instead, which is where your GetStatus results were assigned.  Oh, and use css for what it does, don't use style.

i.e. templates generally substitute in already computed values, they don't
call functions on them (well, they can but that's a special case because the function can not get any parameters in that case).

```
    {% for srv in Srvs %}
    {% csrf_token %}

        <li class="collection-item waves-effect waves-teal " onclick="serverId({{srv.id}})"  id="serverId"><a><i class="mdi-social-public {{srv.color}}" </i> {{ srv.name }} </a></li>
    {% endfor %}
```

*there are lots of little things that look off in your template, like for example the server url - check the **reverse** family of django url functions or the **{% url %}** tag.  but that's alright, get your template to generate then look at the page's source to see what needs fixing.  nothing wrong with getting started on a real live project, but you do want to keep your eyes on the django template tutorial docs as you go.*

Comment: I am also pretty sure that csrf_token doesn't make sense in the loop.  you have a hyperlink, not a form.  try it without first, you can always add it back later.  and i am also not sure about your putting the color/style on the <i> tag because that seems to have no text.  maybe the <a>?